# How to prevent user from visiting the custom login page when they are already authenticated?

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

I've have a middleware to verify if the URL path is "/login" and if the user is authenticated. If both conditions are satisfied, the intention is to redirect the user to the home page ("/"). However, despite the user being authenticated, the redirection to the home page isn't working when attempting to access the login route.

**Middleware Code**

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default withAuth(
  async function middleware(req) {
    const token = await getToken({ req });
    const isAuthenticated = !!token; // RETURN BOOLEAN

    if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") && isAuthenticated) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
    }
  },
  {
    pages: {
      signIn: "/login",
    },
  }
);

// specify on which routes you want to run the middleware
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/login"],
};
```

**Auth Config Code**

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const users = [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "John Smith",
            email: "jsmith",
            password: "Password888",
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Jane Doe",
            email: "jdoe",
            password: "Password888",
          },
        ];

        // Find a user with the provided credentials
        const user = users.find(
          (u) =>
            u.email === credentials.username &&
            u.password === credentials.password
        );

        if (user) {
          // If the user is found, return user data
          // For example, you can return { user: { id: user.id, name: user.name, email: user.email } }
          return user;
        } else {
          // If the user is not found, you can return an error message
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
};
```

**Home Page Code**

```
import { authOptions } from "next-auth";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function Home() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  if (session) {
    return (
      <main className="safeMargin">
        <h1 className="underline">You are login</h1>
      </main>
    );
  } else {
    redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

I implemented the authentication check directly on the login page, and it's work. However, I hope to redirect users away instead of showing them the login page and redirect them away after.

Answer (score 0):

just use the router

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useAuth } from '../hooks/useAuth';

const LoginPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      router.push('/dashboard');
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, router]);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Login form */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

let me know if any wrong .